# Event acting on multiple elements determine which element fired the event

Tags: c#, events, combobox

I have a WindowsForm with several ComboBoxes and associating TextBoxes. When the user changes a ComboBox, I want to insert some text into the associated TextBox.  I would like to re-use the code for all of the ComboBoxes, so that I don't have to have 9 copies of the same code.

How do I determine which ComboBox fired the Event?

Comment: The `sender` parameter of an event should be the triggering control. You'll just need to cast it to the appropriate control type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyCheckbox_Event(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var chk = sender as CheckBox;
    if(chk == null) return;
    string name = chk.Name;
    switch(name){
        case "name1":
        //do something for name 1
        break;
        case "name2":
        //do something for name 2
        break;
        //and so on and so forth
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this realy helped :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Do feel free to rate my answer and mark as correct if this solves your issue.

Comment: I have one issue:<code>var chk = sender as CheckBox;<br/>if(chk == null) return;</code><br/>this does not seam to work the var is alwas null

Comment: The only explanation is that "sender" is not of type CheckBox

Comment: Make sure you are calling the event from a CheckBox component

Comment: Ahh ok i was calling it from a ComboBox but had CheckBox in the code

Comment: My apologies. I used CheckBox in the example, but you were asking about a ComboBox in your question. Still, the fundamental concept is the same. Didn't mean to confuse you.